# Metal uniform<T> vs function constant

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

In MSL you can declare a variable to be a `uniform` type if you can guarantee it'll have the same value for all threads during the kernel dispatch. But doesn't it practically turns this variable into a `function constant`, which is is another very similar MSL feature in my opinion? In fact, I can't think of any situation where optimisation achievable via `uniform` can't be achieved by `function constant`, which seems to be even more versatile allowing conditional bindings and many more.

I guess it's only viable to use `uniform` if some variable can have incalculable number of different values in which case it'd become impractical to compile so many different functions with `function constant`? Still I can't think of such an example, in my experience such variables just became constant input buffers of a kernel (which is uniforms in OpenGL terminology coincidently).

Comment: I guess if a knowingly constant variable is the result of a texture/buffer lookup would be an appropriate example. Passing it in "OpenGL uniform style" would introduce CPU synchronization, `function constant` is inapplicable. But it's a strange situation, can't think of a practical example.

Comment: `uniform` variable is the same across all the threads that are executing the code, but that value is not known at compile time. Which means, that you can run the same pipeline while passing multiple different values of the uniform in multiple different dispatches or draws, even though you haven't recompiled them.  Function constant on the other hand is known at compile time and you can't change it without recompiling the whole pipeline.